# Applying a function to all but one column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to apply a function to all but one column in pandas, whilst maintaining that column as it is originally. I have a working version that does what I need, but it seems unusually long for something so simple. I'm wondering if there is a better approach...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['firstcol','secondcol','thirdcol'],
     data=[['a1',1,'a6.1'],['b2',3,'b9.3'],['c12',4,'c2']])
```

My dataframe is made up of strings and integers. Each column is exclusive of a particular type, and I am looking to standardize so that all columns are numerical (integers or floats as I have some decimal values). So, in the toy data above, I need to transform the first and third columns, and leave the second column alone...

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'secondcol'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'secondcol'].applymap(lambda x: float(re.sub(r'[^\d.]','', x)))
```

For clarity, this line: (1) specifies all but the column named "secondcol", (2) uses the `applymap` and `lambda` functions to remove non-numeric (or decimal) characters, and (3) converts to a float.

This produces the desired output, but as I say isn't overly readable. Have I stumbled across the best way to do this, or is there a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `df.columns.difference` (set nomenclature) to select "all but one column", subset the frame, and apply the operation:

```py
bad_column     = "undesired_column"
other_cols     = df.columns.difference([bad_column])
df[other_cols] = df[other_cols].apply(...)
```

Note that we need to pass an array-like to `.difference`; it won't accept `bad_column` string as is, so we wrap it in a list. If you already have lists of undesired columns, they are put as is, e.g.,

```py
bad_columns    = ["bad_1", "bad_7"]
other_cols     = df.columns.difference(bad_columns)
df[other_cols] = df[other_cols].apply(...)
```

Instead of `.apply`, you can do other things to that subset of course.

---

(answering the original question, which is somewhat more specific than the title reads)

You can select the non-numeric data type columns and replace their values:

```
non_numerics = df.select_dtypes(exclude="number").columns

df[non_numerics] = df[non_numerics].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"[^\d.]", "").astype(float))
```

where I used your regex for replacing but not element-wise with `applymap` but column-wise with `apply` (you can change to `applymap` with your line if you will).

to get

```
>>> df

   firstcol  secondcol  thirdcol
0       1.0          1       6.1
1       2.0          3       9.3
2      12.0          4       2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Readable is in the eye of beholder. Here's what I would do:

```py
import re

import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    columns=['firstcol', 'secondcol', 'thirdcol'],
    data=[['a1', 1, 'a6.1'], ['b2', 3, 'b9.3'], ['c12', 4, 'c2']]
)

df2 = (
    df.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
      .applymap(lambda x: float(re.sub(r'[^\d.]','', x)))
      .join(df.select_dtypes(include='number'))
      .loc[:, df.columns.tolist()]  
)
```